# Convert type in setter method, possible? When yes how?

Tags: c#, get, properties, set

guess I wanted to gernerate a commandline with flags and so on. Flags are of type bool but the commandline is a string like " /activeFlag". Is there a way to program a setter in C# which takes a bool but the getter returns a string?

like

```
private string activeFlag {
 get { return activeFlag; }
 set {
    // the value here should be the bool
    activeFlag = value ? " /activeFlag" : "";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another setter.

```
private string activeFlag { 
 get { return _activeFlag; } 
}
private bool activeFlagByBool { 
 set { 
    // the value here should be the bool 
    _activeFlag = value ? " /activeFlag" : ""; 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There no way to have a property with different data types for its setter and getter.

What you can do is something like this:

```
private bool IsActiveFlagSet { get { return ActiveFlag == " /activeFlag"; } }
private string ActiveFlag { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Marc Yeah you're right.. it's too early =P  I'll edit to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could use a custom `TypeConverter` to achieve the same thing, via `TypeDescriptor`. If you really wanted. Not sure it would be worth it, though, unless you desparately wanted to display it in a `DataGridView`, `PropertyGrid`, or similar.

There is also a separation of concerns issue; the purpose of the flag is to understand a boolean value - the string representation relates only to the UI. You could use a custom attribute:

```
[CommandLine("/activeFlag")]
public bool IsActive {get;set;}
```

and take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, have a look at this project [Automatic Command Line Parsing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/commandlineparser.aspx) I've used this and it is a nice solution.